# SVGs Import as React Component giving a Typescript Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg

##### Issue

I was trying to import `SVG` as `ReactComponent` in one `.tsx` File of `React` App.

---

#### Error

`Cannot find module '../icons/download.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.`
[image]

---

##### Ways Tried

I got some of the ways to resolve it, and I tried them

1. using `svg.d.ts` in `src/` with given config

   ```
   declare module "*.svg" {
    import React from "react";

    export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<
        React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & { title?: string }
    >;

    const src: string;
    export default src;
    }
   ```

and

```
declare module "*.svg" {
    import React from "react";
    const content: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGAttributes<SVGElement>>;
    export default content;
}
```

one by one, and added it to `ts.config` file

```
"include": ["./src/components", "src/svg.d.ts"]
```

but none of them worked

---

---

2. created `./src/@types/assets/index.d.ts` file with config

```
    declare module "*.svg" {
        import React = require("react");
        export const ReactComponent: React.SFC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
        const src: string;
        export default src;
    }

    declare module "*.jpg" {
        const content: string;
        export default content;
    }
    
    declare module "*.png" {
        const content: string;
        export default content;
    }
    
    declare module "*.json" {
        const content: string;
        export default content;
    }
```

and added it to `ts.config`

```
"typeRoots": [
    "./src/@types",
    "./node_modules/@types"
]
```

this also didn't worked.

Please suggest what am I doing wrong or some other way of doing this.